# href to follow URL in broswers location bar

Tags: html

Suppose I had a URL in my browser location bar that read:

```
http://www.example.com/us/books
```

... how do I code the url in the page so that it'll add to the address in the location bar?

**Example**

Url in location bar: `http://www.example.com/us/books`

Url on page: `<a href="./this-title">Read more</a>`

**Desired**

```
http://www.example.com/us/books/this-title
```

No matter what I do, It wont appear after the entire URL. The URL isn't fixed.

Comment: `<a href="/this-title">Read more</a>` try this

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan No, that won't work either.

Comment: <a href="this-title">this is a relative link</a>

Comment: @BrianShamblen You are right, that is a relative link too. But `<a href="./this-title">Read more</a>` also is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach of using a relative path inside a reference does work. But you have to figure out some details which depend on your local situation.

In your case most likely the target url called is `http://www.example.com/us/this-title` (you did not tell us...). This is due to the fact how the browser (not the server!) interprets its current position inside the document hierarchy on the server.

If your base url reads `http://www.example.com/us/books/` (note the trailing "/") then things would work as expected by you! You could even note the relative path as `<a href="this-title">Read more</a>`. This works because the browser recognizes the current position as a folder and assumes the relative path to be located inside. This works for example when the html page holding that reference is delivered by an index document (index.html, index.php or similar) on the server. This is when the trailing slash makes sense, since it denotes that the current url retrieved the content of a folder, not a directoy.

Of course this is only what is happening on the client side. It might be that the server decides to rewrite the url and redirect the browser again. For example by using rewrite rules inside the http server. This is typically done to handle requests to non existing documents.